# Script tag not seen in html source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this angular service called tourSevice.js:

```
var service = angular.module('tourtService', []);

service.factory('Tournament', function($http)
{
    return {
       doLogin: function(token)
       {
           return $http.get('/api/tournament/user/' + token);
       }
    };
});
```

Here is my main app page, which holds all the includes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/services/loginService.js"></script>
<script src="../js/services/tourService.js"></script> <!-- not included -->

<script src="../js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="../js/controllers/homeController.js"></script> <!-- not included -->
<script src="../js/controllers/AppController.js"></script>

<head>
    <title>Application</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But in my chrome dev tools in the page source I see this (some scripts are not included):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/loginService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AppController.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Application</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

No error thrown regarding that this files are missing from the provided path. Angular throws exception because this js files are missing.

What is wrong with it?

**Update**
Here is my main app js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'loginService', 'tourService']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'pages/loginView.html'})
        .when('/home', {templateUrl: '/pages/home.html'})
        .otherwise({templateUrl: '/pages/loginView.html'});
        //.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'pages/loginView.html'});
});

betsApp.controller('appCtrl', function($scope)
{

});
```

Comment: @adeneo, what I need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't looking at a cached version? Or if you're using a build process (e.g. Grunt) that is possibly stripping out some lines from your page? It's probably something along those lines which will be hard for anyone to solve for you except through several guesses like this.

Comment: I have tried to open this page incognito and still they were missing :(

Comment: If you're looking at `view-source` in Chrome (ie not the live DOM), then whatever you see is what your browser is using to output your app, and if you're seeing missing script tags, you're either seeing a page that is cached in your browser (sounds like you're not) or on your server... or the file actually just doesn't have those tags. Again, hard to say what the issue is for you. Sorry.

Comment: Make some visible change(like add some text) in the HTML and check if it's picked up. Most probably your are served cached version of this page.

Comment: You are right no changes taking place... very odd. I am investigating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said in the comments I mad a huge mistake. I was changing the wrong file, there were 2 very similar index.html files one located in the public folder (the one I was changing) and the one located in the app/view folder (this is Laravel project). In order for the changes to take place I had to change the file in app/view and not the file in the public folder.

**Sorry for wasting your time because of my inattentiveness.**